# Convert generic type to enum in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider this generic class -

```
class Person<T>  {
   key : T;
}
```

and another class -

```
class Employee {
  name = "Ujjwal Gupta"
}
```

I want to get the key of the type passed in class Person, kind of treat "key" in Person as enum e.g -

```
const person =  new Person<Employee>();
console.log(person.key.name) // value should be "name", not "Ujjwal Gupta"
```

It is compiled & shows initillisense but doesn't work in run time.

Here is a link to playground - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdgHgCoD5rQG8AofaAa3gE9oAuaLAbiIF8ijRIYBRAWwAcQKSvHiES0NGB6iAvNABEAVQBWygO5gQ0AOIBXPgBcw8lm2DoIB6HySo00OWnhq4t9Bl4ChInAAoAlEzsFigg8AB0ggDmvjbI6OEUlOGS0oFAA

How can i achieve this ?

### Edit1 - What is goal ?

The goal is to let user know what are the keys available inside the class and use it at run time to get value.

e.g -

```
const person =  new Person<Employee>();
person.value(person.key.name);
```

or better consider a method which creates person -

```
functon createPerson(type){
   const person = new Person<type>();
   return person;
}

const person = createPerson(Employee);
person.value(person.key.name);
```

My implementation might be wrong but my intention is to get enum out of supplied type.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, why it should be "name"

Comment: What is the use case here?  This isn't how things work: something like `new Person<Employee>()` will compile to `new Person()`, so no information about `Employee` will be available at runtime; you fail to initialize `key` inside `Person` so `person.key` will be `undefined` and does not have a `name` property (you should use `--strictPropertyInitialization` to catch such errors); even if you fix those, `person.key` will be an `Employee` whose `name` is not `"name"` unless you set it to be that yourself or use `Proxy` objects or something weird... and what is the goal? How would you use it?

Comment: Why not you extend person in Employee class, instantiate new Employer() and access this value through newEmp.name ?

Comment: i have added more information, please have a look

Comment: If someone is writing `person.key.name`, then they presumably already know that the key is `"name"`.  Why would someone ever want to write `person.value(person.key.name)` when they can just write `person.value("name")` or, even better, just `employee.name`?  You could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA7LQw), where `person.key` is either: a snapshot of whatever the keys were when the object was created; or a `Proxy` that just returns `proxy.blargh === "blargh"` for all possible keys... but I really don't understand the use case enough to tell if it's worth the complexity.

Comment: I can write [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mA7LQw) up as an answer if it helps you, but I am still very confused about if this is actually what you want, and if so, why

Comment: this works @jcalz, you can add it as answer. Infact i thought of same thing but hoping if there is any better way.